# Are MANIFEST.in options 'global-include', 'include-global' supposed to work with 'bdist_rpm'?

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools, distutils

With `setup.py sdist` I can package a directory tree of non-python files by specifying 'global-include' or 'recursive-include' options in `MANIFEST.in`. Is there a way to include same arbitrary directory tree into RPM created by `setup.py bdist_rpm`?

Specifying each individual file in setup.py's 'package_data' works, but it is not convenient.

My findings so far:

Seems that in case of bdist_rpm, 'MANIFEST.in' settings have no effect: the generated RPM does not include what's written in the generated 'MANIFEST' file.

For example, I'm trying to pack 'pkg1' directory here, including the whole directory `extras`:

```
├── MANIFEST
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pkg1
│   ├── extras
│   │   ├── dir1
│   │   │   ├── dir2
│   │   │   │   └── script2.pl
│   │   │   └── script1.pl
│   │   └── README
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pkg2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module1.py
├── README
└── setup.py
```

'setup.py sdist' does that as expected (the 'extra' directory is in place):

```
# python setup.py sdist
# tar tzf ./dist/module1-1.0.tar.gz
module1-1.0/
module1-1.0/README
module1-1.0/setup.py
module1-1.0/PKG-INFO
module1-1.0/pkg1/
module1-1.0/pkg1/pkg2/
module1-1.0/pkg1/pkg2/module1.py
module1-1.0/pkg1/pkg2/__init__.py
module1-1.0/pkg1/extras/
module1-1.0/pkg1/extras/dir1/
module1-1.0/pkg1/extras/dir1/script1.pl
module1-1.0/pkg1/extras/dir1/dir2/
module1-1.0/pkg1/extras/dir1/dir2/script2.pl
module1-1.0/pkg1/__init__.py
```

, but 'setup bdist_rpm' does not include the 'extra' directory contents into RPM:

```
# python setup.py bdist_rpm --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 
# rpm -qlp dist/module1-1.0-1.noarch.rpm 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/module1-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/__init__.pyo
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/__init__.pyo
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/module1.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/module1.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg1/pkg2/module1.pyo
```

`setup.pl` and `MANIFEST.in` are the same in both cases:

```
# cat MANIFEST.in
global-include *.pl

# cat setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name="module1",version="1.0",packages=["pkg1", "pkg1.pkg2"])
```